# Convert time interval into decimal hours in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a time interval in the format '88:52:57'
I need to convert it into a decimal hours in the format 88.88

How can I do this?

I have the data initially loaded as a varchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use left, right and substring to extract the values and then do some calculations.

```
declare @S varchar(8) = '88:52:57';

select left(@S, 2) + substring(@S, 4, 2)/60.0 + right(@S, 2)/60.0/60.0;
```

If you not always have two digit values you can use parsename to get the values instead.

```
declare @S varchar(20) = '088:052:057';

select parsename(S.X, 3) + parsename(S.X, 2)/60.0 + parsename(S.X, 1)/60.0/60.0
from (select replace(@S, ':', '.')) as S(X)
```

Comment: That will do it. However, if I get a time interval in the format '121:32:43' I get issues

Comment: You might replace the first "2" with a `SELECT CHARINDEX(':','88:52:57')` and the second with a `SELECT CHARINDEX(':','88:52:57',CHARINDEX(':','88:52:57')+1)` or you use splitting like I did in my answer.

Comment: @Shnugo Added a version that works for different length value parts.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I like the usage of `parsename` here. +1 from my side

Comment: I getting arithmetic overflows when I run this against a table instead of a single value

I now have a working select but it looks pretty dirty

`select part1 + part2
from(
select left(Resolution_Time,CHARINDEX(':',Resolution_Time)-1) part1
     , substring(Resolution_Time, CHARINDEX(':',Resolution_Time,CHARINDEX(':',Resolution_Time))+1, 2)/60.0 + right(Resolution_Time, 2)/60.0/60.0 part2
from ds_fd_tickets
) as data`

Comment: @tom That will happen if you for example have data that is not on the form `HH.MM.SS`.

Comment: I staged the 3 date parts in another table then merged it back into the original table. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this (best create an UDF from this):

First I split the Time-Variable on its double dots via XML. The rest is simple calculation...

```
DECLARE @YourTime VARCHAR(100)='88:52:57';

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@YourTime,':','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) TimeParts
)
,TimeFract AS
(
    SELECT TimeParts.value('/x[1]','float') AS HourPart
           ,CAST(TimeParts.value('/x[2]','int') * 60 + TimeParts.value('/x[3]','int') AS FLOAT) Seconds
    FROM Splitted
)
SELECT HourPart + Seconds/3600   
FROM TimeFract
```

The result

```
88,8825
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, solution is based on conversions, making it safe, if the format is always (h)h:mi:ss:

```
DECLARE @S varchar(8) = '88:52:57';
SELECT
  CAST(REPLACE(left(@S, 2), ':', '') as int)+
  CAST(CAST(CAST('0:'+RIGHT(@S, 5) as datetime) as decimal(10,10)) * 24 as decimal(2,2))
```

Result:

```
88.88
```